# Django define which urls loaded and which temolate show

Tags: django, django-models, django-views

i have many html files (all of them are same) i useing `base.html` , but i want to define which html show, for examole when `something.com/love` loaded show love content, if `something.com/game` loaded show game content. how define this? and where define? in `views.py` or in `html`?

```
{% for lov in lovess %}
                       {% if forloop.last %}
                        love Content text{{lov.body_text}}
                       {% endif %}
                       {% endfor %}
```

if game urls loaded shows game body text.
i do not want to copy paste and create many html files (DRY) , i want to used one basic which are extends in html files.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

views.py
Code with your style:

```
if request.path == "/love/":
    temolate = "love.html"
if request.path == "/game/":
    temolate = "game.html"
return render(request, temolate)
```

base.html:

```
......
{%block content%}
{%endblock%
......
```

love.html:

```
{%extends base.html%}
...
{%block content%}
contents of love.
{%endblock%}
...
```

Comment: What do you mean in xxx? or yy?

Comment: {% if request.path == '/contact/' %}
    <p>You are in Contact</p>
{% elif request.path == '/shop/' %}
    <p>You are in Shop</p>
{% endif %}   like this?